# simple form using bootstrap and php script completely not working

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a html code for a simple contact form using bootstrap styling and the action linked in form tag to form_check.php
I have been hitting my head hard as clicking the submit button doesnt perform any action and gives no output for even the simplest php script.

Heres the html part:

[image]

and heres the php script part in its simplest form still it is not working

[image]

Please help me out as even clicking the submit button performs no action at all.

Comment: can you use `input type=submit`intsead of `button`

Comment: @Aditya Sinha You can use `<button></button>` if you want. **No need to replace with `<input>`** just replace the type value from `button` to **`submit`**. You can have `submit` value for button's `type` attribute too.

Comment: Go through this basics: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of using a button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

The reason your form is not submitting is because `<button type="button">` is clickable yes, but without an event handler, nothing will happen.

However, you can simply change `<button type="button"` to `<button type="submit"`. Either one of these will work.

Answer (score 1):

use ,

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

instead of

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" >submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change the button to an input and give it the attribute type="submit"

Buttons don't submit forms.

Comment: Button's can submit forms. You just need to have `submit` as value for `type` instead of `button`. Check basics: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">` just change this line:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" >submit</button>
```

to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" >submit</button>
```

OR if you want js solution try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$('#myForm').submit();" >submit</button>
```

Where `myForm` is id of your `form`